# SQLAlchemy - attaching an expression to a model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I sometimes need to reuse a certain SQL expression in different queries. If the expression queries the same table in all cases, the model seems like a good place to put it in. However, I don't always need the scalar property and if I don't need it, I don't want to implement it.

Here's how I do it:

```
 @hybrid_property
 def some_property(self):
     """Allows the query-level expression to exist."""
     raise NotImplemented

 @some_property.expression
 def some_property(cls):
     """Query blah blah blah."""
     return case(
         ... snip ...
     ).label('some_property')
```

Now, the scalar implementation does nothing (raises `NotImplemented`). How can I avoid having to write it?

I cannot make that expression a class attribute because I need to refer to the class in it and you cannot refer to a class in class-level code:

```
class A(object):
    c = A  # NameError
```

I theoretically can make it a class-level property but there is no good implementation for that.

The only alternative I can think of is creating the expression later, after the class is created and assigning it back to the class. Which is wicked.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do this:

```
@declared_attr
def some_property(cls):
    """Query blah blah blah."""
    return case(
        ... snip ...
    ).label('some_property')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try implementing it as a [column property](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property). A column property is like a hybrid property with only the expression part (which is what you want, right?). There are some limitations, but for me this usually works out. Using `deferred=true` you can avoid having it evaluated when not needed.

```
some_property = column_property(
  select(**some column**).where(**some conditon**),
  deferred=true
)
```